# youtube-dl delete files that are no longer in a playlist

Tags: command-line, youtube, youtube-dl

I have a watch later playlist on YouTube. I both add videos to it and remove watched ones constantly. I use

```
youtube-dl <playlist_url>
```

to download the entire playlist into a current folder. The idea is to keep this folder in sync with the playlist, in other words to delete videos from the local folder that are no longer in the playlist.
Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: You can use [`youtube-playlist-sync`](https://github.com/chewett/youtube-playlist-sync)

Comment: Except `youtube-playlist-sync` wont take all the parameters that `youtube-dl` does to get subtitles etc :(